# Forge - inconsistent output from python script and terminal command

Tags: python, curl, autodesk-forge

I am following [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/) tutorial to convert a .sldprt to .obj file. I wanted to accomplish this conversion using a python script, and I found a [script](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/sample-scripts-basic-workflow-translating-model-python) online that accomplishes this to the point where it uploads the file to the server and begins the conversion. In step 3 of the tutorial (Verify the job is Complete), when I type the following command into the command line:

```
curl -X 'GET' -H 'Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN' -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/MYURN/manifest'
```

I get an appropriate response (see image below):

[image]

However, doing the same thing from Python script gives me the following output:

[image]

My Python script is as below:

```
### Verify if translation is complete and get the outURN
url = BASE_URL + 'modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + urn + '/manifest'
headers = {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
content = eval(r.content)
print("==========================================")
print(content)
print("==========================================")
```

I have no idea whats the difference between the two (terminal command and the command given from python script). Can someone point out what the problem here is?

Comment: Don't do `eval(r.content)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or better yet, listen to [extraction.finished](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/extraction.finished/) event, which notifies when a translation is done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had to pause for some time after beginning the conversion to allow some time for the cloud to convert .sldprt to .stl. The solution is constantly poll the 'status' key and proceed only when the status changes from 'pending' to 'success'